# absorption spectrum of water at different wavelengths

Tags: spectroscopy, periodic-table, mass-spectrometry, spectrophotometry

I know I can get the visible absorption spectrum of water https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_absorption But how does one go about getting and testing what the absorption spectrum is for a glass of water in the audio range of (0hz to 20000hz) I know nasa uses water to absorb sound https://youtu.be/08aHEmuzMLI.
How can I measure what the sound absorption spectrum is in a glass of water?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this (1) belongs on physics section (2) OP has to explain why he wants to measure in a glass. How big is the glass? thickness of glass walls diameter of glass Et cetera, et cetera, et cetera!

Comment: Music.SE has a tag called "Sound", whose description reads: "Sound is a mechanical wave that is an oscillation of pressure transmitted through some medium (like air or water), composed of frequencies which are within the range of hearing." It seems like this might be more likely to get you a good answer.  There are a variety of sensors for measuring sound intensity at different frequencies; and even a properly tuned piano could be a reliable source of frequencies up to 6000hz anyway, and there are certainly better solutions than that depending on the accuracy of frequency that you require.